# loop backwards until certain character found (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a situation where I have an array of strings, and would like to append characters to a sections of strings within the array which fall between parenthesis.

For example, if my array is:

```
['Lorem', '(ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit)', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit']
```

I would like to return something like:

```
['Lorem', '(ipsum-foo', 'dolor-foo', 'sit-foo)', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit']
```

**EDIT:**

Hello all, 
I apologise for not adding my initial code. It's within a lot of other stuff but currently looks something like this:

```
                // other stuff up above (incl. a backwards loop k)  
                else {  
                    // if it has a certain ending, save to mostRecentTag
                    if (notArray[k].search(/\./) >= 0) { // 
                        var mostRecentTagArray = notArray[k].match(/\.[a-zA-Z,/-]+/); 
                        mostRecentTag = mostRecentTagArray[0]; // mostRecentTag = keyword field code 
                    }
                    // if doesn't meet criteria above, change ending to .af
                    else if (mostRecentTag == "") { // TO DO fix this line: (exercise OR physical.ti) --> "exercise"[ti] OR "physical"[ti]
                        notArray[k] = notArray[k] + ".af"; 
                    }
                    // adds mostRecentTag to the end 
                    else { 
                        notArray[k] = notArray[k] + mostRecentTag; 
                    }
```

(This is a partial clip of a much larger piece)

However, as it stands, an expression such as:

exercise OR ((exercise OR physical).ti OR physical)

Will get changed to:

exercise[ti] OR ((exercise[ti] OR physical[ti]) OR physical)

Whereas I would prefer that it evaluate to:

exercise OR ((exercise[ti] OR physical[ti]) OR physical)

I hope this all makes sense and I apologise for the partial and confusing code.

Comment: have you tried anything at all yet?

Comment: Why `sit)-foo` instead of `sit-foo)`?

Comment: @Dalorzo please stop undoing my edits

Comment: Have you started writing some code to do this?  Edit your question to show the code you have and ask a specific question about any issues you have with your code.

Comment: @Xufox The OP probably just made a typo in her question

Comment: so many people is editing this post, so this `(ipsum, dolor, sit)` is string?

Comment: hi Paul -- Yes! I have tried creating loops and if-then statements and variables that evaluate to either true or false but nothing seems to be working quite right.

Comment: @Amanda generally folks prefer if you show what you've tried here.

Comment: @Amanda please demonstrate what you've tried and where you got stuck. As it stands now it looks like you're asking the community to do all the work for you

Comment: is `(ipsum-foo, dolor-foo, sit-foo)` a single element of the array or 3 elements? it's not clear as they are not strings in your question

Comment: post your code.

Comment: I apologise all -- I am new. I have posted my code demonstrating where I am at right now.

Comment: @JaromandaX 3 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case js does not know ('ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit') as an string. If you set this code:

```
var arr = ['Lorem', ('ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit'), 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit'];
alert(arr[1]);
```

You will see only 'sit' in alert(the last one). So it is better to get all of the array as one string:

```
var str = ['Lorem, (ipsum, dolor, sit), amet, consectetur, adipiscing, elit'];
```

and

```html
<div id="a">
  Lorem, (ipsum, dolor, sit), amet, consectetur, adipiscing, elit
  </div><br>
<input type="button" value="Change" onclick="change()" />
<script>
  function change(){
     var str = document.getElementById('a').innerHTML;
        var arr = str.split(',');
        var index;
        var paranthess;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i].indexOf('(') > 0)
            {
                arr[i] += '-foo';
                for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[j].indexOf(')') == -1)
                        arr[j] += "-foo";
                    else
                    {
                        var last = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = [arr[j].slice(0, arr[j].length - 1), "-foo", arr[j].slice(arr[j].length - 1)].join('');
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        
        alert(arr.join());
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: I wouldn't have made wither assumption of the array that you made

Comment: thank you! I agree -- this would be a much easier problem if the whole thing was just one string. For other reasons, each word is an element in the array, but I am starting to think that I may need to rethink the entire structure of my program...

Comment: @JaromandaX we have not such thing ['Lorem', ('ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit'),... if you add console.log(arr[1]); it logs 'sit'. So there is no way to access the strings in pranthess .

Comment: @FarzinKanzi I apologise -- somebody else edited it to look like that. What the array actually looks like is: ['Lorem', '(ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit)']

Comment: No problem @Amanda. If my answer helped you please point that with check or upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @FarzinKanzi this is very helpful!

Comment: You welcome @Amanda. I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to solve this type of issue, but generally speaking you want to isolate the target substring, modify it, then replace the original value with the modified value. One way to accomplish this is to use a regular expression to match the substring.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/agqb8ycd/

```
var arr = ['Lorem', '(ipsum, dolor, sit)', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit'];
var tester = /\((.*)?\)/; // Find strings which contain parens () that contain characters i.e., (adsf)

// Operate on the array
arr.forEach(function (content, i) {
  var matchedContent = content.match(tester);

    // Noop strings that don't match the tester
  if (!matchedContent) {
    return;
  }

  // Now we'll need to operate on those substrings within the parens individually. In this case they are separated by commas, so the most simple way is to break the string into an array of strings and mutate them.
  var substrings = matchedContent[1].split(',');

  // Mutate the substrings
  substrings = substrings.map(function (substring) {
    return substring + '-foo';
  });

  // Since we matched on the group within the regular expression, we will have to restore the parens lost by the matcher
  var mutatedContent = '(' + substrings.join(', ') + ')';

  // Overwrite the original value in the array
  arr[i] = mutatedContent;
});
```

Comment: thank you! This all makes sense, but I'm still having trouble conceptualizing how to isolate the elements of the array that match the condition. As it stands, each word is a different element, rather than the entire sequence being one element in the array, which would be a much easier problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the problem of isolating different portions of the array? Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve beyond finding elements which match "(foo, bar)" ?

Answer (score 0):

This one involves the use of some regex, and I think it may be a tad more readable than some of the other options.

```
var data = ['Lorem', '(ipsum, dolor, sit)', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit'];

var updated = data.map((item) => { 
    var res = /\((.*)\)/.exec(item); 
    if(!res) return item;
    var modified = res[1].split(',').map((word) => { return word + '-foo'; });
    return '(' + modified.join(',') + ')';
});


console.log(updated);
```

working fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/pwkf9L9m/

Answer (score 0):

IF there will never be a `,` in the array items it's quite easy to make a single string out of the array using join
use replace to add the -foo in the string
and split the tring to an array again

```
var arr = ['Lorem', '(ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit)', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit'];
var result = arr
    .join(',')
    .replace(/(\(.*)\)/g, '$1-foo)')
    .split(',');
```

IF on the other hand, you may have `,` in the items, you need an extra step to "hide" the `,` - I'm using encodeURIComponent/decodeURIComponent

```
var arr = ['Lorem', '(ipsum', 'dol,or', 'sit)', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit'];
var result = arr.map(function(item) {
        return encodeURIComponent(item);
    })
    .join(',')
    .replace(/(\(.*)\)/g, '$1-foo)')
    .split(',')
    .map(function(item) {
        return decodeURIComponent(item);
    });
```